# Android how to go new layout android from current layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my code. What should I change or add to go to another layout? I am doing QR code scanner ,I am trying to do when it scan if the code is "1234" it will go to the new layout name is abcd.xml.

```
package wj.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class OCTotActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
public void onClick (View view){
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    integrator.initiateScan();
}
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
      IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
      if (scanResult != null) {
        // handle scan result
          String barcode;

          barcode = scanResult.getContents();{
              if (barcode.equals("1234")){
                  setContentView(R.layout.abcd);
              }

              }

          EditText etBarcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etBarcode);

          etBarcode.setText(barcode);
      }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to nest both main and abcd in a [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html).  FrameLayout is a stack of child views and can show one of them at a time.

> Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top.

Here is a sample portion of a layout that would utilize a FrameLayout and reuse your existing layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include android:id="@+id/main" layout="@layout/main" />
    <include android:id="@+id/abcd" layout="@layout/abcd" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Then in onCreate, find abcd and set its visibility to View.INVISIBLE:

```
findViewById(R.id.abcd).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

When your barcode equals 1234, then do something like:

```
// Show the abcd layout
findViewById(R.id.abcd).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
// Hide the main layout
findViewById(R.id.main).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: Why it this thing come out "The application has stopped unexpectedly"?

Comment: You probably ran into an exception which crashed your application.  Look into LogCat to see what the exception was.  If you are using Eclipse, you can get to it by switching to the Debug perspective, making sure your device is selected and then setting the filter to Error.

Comment: That is frame layout is add to main.xml or abcd.xml or both?

Comment: FrameLayout will contain both main and abcd.